# Spring Batch: Read data from Kafka and write to a file

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch.
I am working on a requirement where I need to read data from Kafka and create files out of the data read.

After some research, I learnt that I will need to use Spring Integration to connect and read data from Kafka.

I have built a Spring batch Application in which I am using Spring Integration to connect and read data from Kafka.

I am stuck at this point, on how to pass the data read from Kafka to Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter.

I would like to know if the approach I have taken to read data from Kafka (using Spring Integration) is correct? If yes, how do I pass the data read from Kafka to ItemWriter.

If the approach is wrong, what is the best approach to implement this requirement in Spring Batch.

Thanks,
OpenSource Explorer

Comment: So, you do have a spring-batch Listener (custom I guess) that reads from kafka ?

Comment: I have a Spring Integration Kafka Consumer to read from kafka....

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch provides a `JmsItemReader`.  I'd expect you could write a Kafka based `ItemReader` that works in a similar way, reading each message from Kafka as an item per regular Spring Batch paradigms.  You can view the code for the `JmsItemReader` on Github here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/jms/JmsItemReader.java

Comment: Sorry for a comment on an old answer. KafkaItemReader does this now, right?
I tried it but once it reads all the messages, it stops & shuts down. I would rather want it to keep running and wait for new messages (if chunk size is reached, then process and wait again). Is this possible?

Comment: While it could be possible, that really isn't batch processing.  Batch processing should have a finite amount of data to process in each "batch".

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Although it limits Kafka as a streaming platform. One would have to keep launching the Job, and with higher throughput wouldn't it be an overhead?

Comment: Also, just a quick question. When you say 'it could be possible", are you implying to run the KafkaItemReader in an infinite state?
Can we do it by NOT returning null from reader? 
Please suggest.